# Emulate OSX Terminal to test Portability

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I am writing several shell scripts using Ubuntu/bash and I would like to ensure that they are portable to OSX.

I have previously had trouble when I tried to use non-portable behavior of certain commands. Is there anything like an emulator for another shell environment?

I'm looking for an option besides just researching the portability of each command that I use.

Comment: Is there a way to get osX to run in a VirtualBox? Probably not as easy as downloading a Ubuntu iso, or is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terminal.app is just a GUI, like xterm. It doesn't execute scripts. OS X uses bash, just like Ubuntu. It may, however, use a different version. For instance, OS X 10.9 uses bash version 3.2.51.

What you're describing is not Terminal and probably isn't bash. It's probably "the entirety of the command line tools that are installed by default." Things like grep, sed, and cut, and in practice you mean "the entire OS." There is no environment other than the OS that is going to capture all of those. Even if they did, you'd still need to worry about numerous other portability concerns like whether there is /proc filesystem (there isn't one on OS X).

Do you really mean to suggest that it only has to run on Ubuntu and OS X? FreeBSD is quite different. And there are many platforms that don't include all the GNU extensions that are common on Linux. In principle you could write to the POSIX standard, which they are all supposed to follow, but that won't really take you that far. In practice, the only way to know that you're portable to a platform is to test it on that platform.

But short version: no. You have to research first. And then you have to actually test it on each version of each platform you support.

There is another option though: don't use bash and don't use the low-level command line tools like grep. Use a higher-level language that you know will be on the target platform like Python, Perl, or Ruby. Then you just have to work to an old enough version of these languages and stay within the standard library. That's typically much easier to keep portable than bash scripts.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but an answer nonetheless. The point about "entirety of CL tools..." is especially salient, I was missing that completely.